# Android media player stop

Tags: android

I am working on one message tracing application. If i received message i show one dialog box with message text and play selected sound.

When my broadcast receiver is called i call dialog box activity which i have set Theme/dialog box in manifest. Everything is working fine.

**Query:**

Suppose on 1st message dialog box is showing and song is playing and at the same time one more message came then my one more sound starts means two sounds are running at same time and so on.

**I want if one song is playing and second message came then first sound should stop and second sound should start from beginning.**

i Have also implemented this thing

if(media.isPlaying) method. but it always returns false..because on every new message new media player instance is created and it returns false.

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: You can use Application class which will help you to use same mediaplayer instance.
In android each application have single instance of Application class if mentioned in manifest.Whenever application is started this application class is instantiated first. you can use this application class as a global store which will store your current mediaplayer instance which you can use while second sms comes.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you pls share me any example for the same so that i can implement it..

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new media player instance for every message. For example check something like

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
if (mediaPlayer == null){ 
   mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

Then the first time your dialog message appears start the media player by doing something like

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song.uri);
```

Or something like this. Now if a new message comes in you can checkif media player is already playing (since now there is only one mediaplayer instance) and reset it before setting its data source like this.

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
}
```